# What does these phrase "he is on the field" and "all layers of play shed off as..." mean in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning

"Chanyeol is as intense when he kisses as he is on the field, all layers of play shed off as he just.. conquers."
I tried to look up the words in dictionary but still i couldnt get what it means.
Someone help me please.

Comment: Title of book? Context? Is Chanyeol a {soccer/football/hockey/polo} player? Did you look up **all** the different meanings of "field"?

Comment: Please include the research IN your question, it's not enough to say "I looked the words up". Maybe you didn't look hard enough? P.S. Someone who writes "pls" (what's wrong with writing "please"?) on an English website, shows disrespect to users who spend time posting answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Chanyeol is either a footballer, or some other field-based sport (rugby, maybe cricket) or he's a general or soldier who fights in pitched battles (or tournaments). The phrase "on the field" usually references how someone plays a field-based sport or performs in battle. You probably got a lot of references for "in the field" when you looked it up, and it is similar, but "on the field" is more specific to sport or battle (as you can see if you look at the books contributing to the results in [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+field&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20field%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Con%20the%20field%3B%2Cc0)). Whatever the sport, he plays it "intensely".

The second phrase "all layers of play shed off" relates to the first. Kissing is no longer a game so his playfulness is cast off. The word "shed" here is the verb meaning. From [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/shed), first definition from American Heritage:

> shed 1
>
> a. To have (a growth or covering) be disconnected or fall off by a natural process: a tree shedding its leaves; a snake shedding its skin; a dog shedding its hair.
>
> b. To rid oneself of (something not wanted or needed): I shed 25 pounds as a result of my new diet.
>
> c. To take off (an article of clothing).

The layers of playfulness (when he plays the sport) are dropped when he is kissing. The word "conquers" suggests he's more likely a general in an army than a footballer.

Comment: Lovely detailed answer to an off-topic question. Wish I could upvote.

Comment: No problem @Mari-LouA. I added it because the question was less easy than I first assumed. I tried searching for "on the field" and got a bunch of "in the field" hits. I actually had to try to find a suitable "on the field" reference! And then the ngrams were more about historical warfare (or electrical engineering!) rather than football. I was relieved to see that your comment showed that you thought it meant sport, too!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I finally understand the meaning of the sentence.